# Pass a clean parameter through URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

I'm using localhost, and in my index.php page I have this code:

```
<? echo 'LANG IS '.$_GET['lang']; ?>
```

When I type localhost on the URL it only shows LANG IS, obviously, but if I type localhost/en I see a 404 Not Found message. I have to type localhost?lang=en to show my index.php code. I want to type localhost/en instead of localhost?lang=en and get the same result.

I'm using Apache2 and I have mod_rewrite enabled. I also have a .htaccess file with this code (I have changed and tested it a lot of times):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+|)/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I have been reading about .htaccess and clean urls for days but I couldn't make this work. Any ideas? Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your .htaccess isn't even enabled. **Verify it first**

To check if your `.htaccess` is enabled try putting same random/garbage text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

It it is not enabled then then you will need `AllowOverride All` line in `<Directory "/var/www/`>` section.

Once it is enabled following rule should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: You are right, I have mod_rewrite enabled but my .htaccess is not working. Where do I have to write AllowOverride All? In apache2.conf?

Comment: Yes that is done in apache2.conf in the `<Directory "/var/www/>` section. This will require apache restart also.

Comment: Now I have this on that apache2.conf section:
`<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>`

Comment: ya looks good, restart Apache and rerun that .htaccess verification.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of the leading slash in the pattern:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+|)/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

URI's that are sent through rules in the htaccess files have the leading slash stripped off so the pattern needs to omit it.

Comment: Thank you so much, however I did it, after that I restarted all, but same 404 page when I type localhost/en again.

Comment: @user3198727 is the htaccess file in your document root?

Comment: Yes, I am using Kubuntu and I have .htaccess in /var/www/, where is index.php too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably in the regular expression.
Try with this one:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/ /index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you, I pasted your code, but still same problem:

Not Found
The requested URL /en/ was not found on this server.